# How does the compiler understand Nullables?

Tags: c#, nullable

If I have a method:

```
protected int CalculateActualDuration(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate) {
        if (startDate.HasValue && endDate.HasValue) { 
            return Math.Abs((int)(endDate.Value.Subtract(startDate.Value).TotalMinutes));
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

I am able to call the method by passing in both a DateTime? and a DateTime. So how does the compiler understand the difference?

Does that mean if I pass in a DateTime Value, the if statement will essentially be soemthing like

```
if (true && true)
```

and all the *.value has been changed to the proper objects? So all endDate.Value are all now EndDates?

Does the compiler cast all parameters that are not Nullables into Nullables during runtime?

Comment: The answer to your final question is "yes". Think of a nullable DateTime as a normal DateTime with a Boolean glued to it that indicates its nullity. Now is it clear how the compiler could deal with converting a normal DateTime to a nullable DateTime?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Everything in your method remains the same, and the `startDate` and `endDate` parameters are still instances of the [`Nullable<T>` struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx).

When you pass a "normal" `DateTime` to the method, you're taking advantage of the [implicit conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131346(v=vs.110).aspx) specified in the `Nullable<T>` struct:

```
public static implicit operator Nullable<T>(T value) {
    return new Nullable<T>(value);
}
```

From the MSDN page linked above:

> If the *value* parameter is not **null**, the [Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the new [Nullable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx) value is initialized to the value parameter and the [HasValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094(v=vs.110).aspx) property is initialized to **true**.